# Visual Studio 2015 string.h inconsistent annotations

Tags: c, visual-studio-2015, sal

I am using visual studio 2015 and i've also installed ( and reinstalled ) the latest sdk. I started a new project and set the warning level, i've also set "Treat warnings as errors" and i've set to run static code analysis on build. A simple main.c which contains the following code will output some interesting SAL annotation warnings.

code:

```
// main.c
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("wtf?");
    return 0;
}
```

Error output:

```
c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\string.h(130): warning C28252: Inconsistent annotation for 'strcpy': _Param_(1) has 'SAL_writableTo(elementCount(_String_length_(__formal(1,parameter1))+1))' on the prior instance. See <no file>(0). 
c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\string.h(130): warning C28253: Inconsistent annotation for 'strcpy': _Param_(1) has 'SAL_writableTo(elementCount(_String_length_(_Source)+1))' on this instance. See <no file>(0).
```

Additional remarks:

- found out this happens only on Release builds ( on Debug it works just fine)
- also happens only if the source is .c ( works fine in both release/debug with .cpp )

Solutions tried so far:

- Reinstalling visual studio 2015 + sdk
- tried to #pragma warning(suppress:28253) inside de string.h header but it won't let me modify that header

On several bug submits/tickets i've found some microsoft dude said it was fixed in the latest sdk, and also posted a link to the download page vor vs2015 community ( which i redownloaded and reinstalled yet again ) but it still doesn't seem to work ( for me at least

I will probably continue the project without the "Treat warnings as errors" for now but i would appreciate a lot if somenoe could give me an elegant solution without small hacks/workarounds.

Thank you in advance,
Cheers!

**UPDATE 1**
Temporary Solution:

```
#define SAFE_INCLUDE_GUARD_BEGIN __pragma(warning(push)) \
                                 __pragma(warning(disable:28253)) \
                                 __pragma(warning(disable:28252)) 

#define SAFE_INCLUDE_GUARD_END   __pragma(warning(pop))

SAFE_INCLUDE_GUARD_BEGIN
// broken microsoft header includes go here ( like Windows.h, etc )
SAFE_INCLUDE_GUARD_END
```

Comment: Hmya, a pretty classic agile bug.  These SDK releases come fast and furious and are *not* well debugged.  Getting updates to customer machines is not agile yet.  If you need to get your job done then *don't* rely on the latest SDK version, let somebody else debug it.  Or submit the bug report where they belong, not here.

Comment: submitting a ticket to help support actually costs money. Also it's not for my job, it's for a personal project. I actually never use the latest sdk at work ( i test that it works on some spare laptop before updating ), but I had to reinstall windows on my personal laptop due to some crappy drivers issue, so i'm stuck with the latest sdk and wdk ( which also has some problems btw )